# Inner join eliminate duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

Schema:
[image]

Query:

```
 SELECT avto.Marka,SUM(OtrabotanoMachine_hours) as 'work hours',SUM(sec.Hours) as Downtime,CONVERT(group_concat(concat(prostoy.Prichina,'=',sec.Hours) separator ';') USING 'utf8') as 'downtime reasons',CONVERT(group_concat(concat(VipolnennayaRabota,'=',V_raboty) separator ';') USING 'utf8') as 'performed works'
FROM
jos_addRabotyAndProstoyMain main 
INNER JOIN avto ON main.Marka=avto.ID_Avto
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT id_fk, SUM(Hours) AS Hours, Prostoy
   FROM jos_addRabotyAndProstoySecond 
   GROUP BY id_fk,Prostoy) sec ON sec.id_fk = main.id 
INNER JOIN prostoy ON sec.Prostoy = prostoy.ID_Prosyoy
GROUP BY avto.Marka
```

Wrong result:

```
 | Marka   | work hours  |downtime| downtime reasons      | performed works|
 |JCB-90QX |      44     |    7   |lack of materials=2;   | work=51;       |
 |         |             |        |machine malfunction=1; | work=51;       |               
 |         |             |        |Others=3;              | work=51;       |
 |         |             |        |unscheduled repairs=1  | work=51;       |
```

The columns "work hours" and "performed works" contain duplicates. How eliminate duplicates?

I need result like this:

```
| Marka   | work hours  |downtime| downtime reasons      | performed works|
|JCB-90QX |      11     |    7   |lack of materials=2;   | work=51;       |
|         |             |        |machine malfunction=1; |                |               
|         |             |        |Others=3;              |                |
|         |             |        |unscheduled repairs=1  |                |
```

Update [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5016/1)

Comment: duplicates are created in table `jos_addRabotyAndProstoyMain`, but i don't know how eliminate duplicates.

Comment: Do you have some test data we can use? We would need the create table statements as well. Adding them to your question would help? the Putting it in a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) would be nice.

Comment: Added, please check.

Comment: Thank you - that is helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is to add a `DISTINCT` clause to the columns where you want to use unique data.

Try this (taken from your SQL Fiddle):

```
 SELECT avto.Marka,SUM(distinct OtrabotanoMachine_hours) as 'work hours',SUM(sec.Hours) as Downtime,CONVERT(group_concat(concat(prostoy.Prichina,'=',sec.Hours) separator ';') USING 'utf8') as 'downtime reasons',CONVERT(group_concat(distinct concat(VipolnennayaRabota,'=',V_raboty) separator ';') USING 'utf8') as 'performed works'
FROM
jos_addRabotyAndProstoyMain main 
INNER JOIN avto ON main.Marka=avto.ID_Avto
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT id_fk, SUM(Hours) AS Hours, Prostoy
   FROM jos_addRabotyAndProstoySecond 
   GROUP BY id_fk,Prostoy) sec ON sec.id_fk = main.id 
INNER JOIN prostoy ON sec.Prostoy = prostoy.ID_Prosyoy
GROUP BY avto.Marka
```

However, it is important to note that I am not 100% sure how the `OtrabotanoMachine_hours` is set up. If it is possible for there to be two legitimate separate entries with the same values, it will de-dupe them.

Comment: Edited SQL Fiddle(Add more rows). Values in `OtrabotanoMachine_hours` can be repeated. `SUM(distinct OtrabotanoMachine_hours)` in this query not solution:(